# ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor Model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to bind a dropdown to my model, but I am having issues. My model that is passed into my HttpPost function is NULL, but only if I try to bind to the "product" object's CategoryID field. If I exclude trying to bind to product.CatgeoryID, then the IncidentNumber string is not null. Thanks for any input.

Here is my model.

```
public class BIFireTypeModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Product()
    {
        CategoryID = 0;
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
//
// GET: /BasicIdentification/
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult BasicIdentificationIndex()
{
    Product newproduct = new Product();
    ViewModelData vmd = new ViewModelData();
    vmd.product = newproduct;
    vmd.product.CategoryID = 2; 
    ViewBag.Categories = GetItems(); 
    return View(vmd); 
}        

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BasicIdentificationIndex(ViewModelData product)
{      
    ViewBag.Categories = GetItems();         
    return View(product);           
}

public List<BIFireTypeModel> GetItems()
{
    List<BIFireTypeModel> categories = new List<BIFireTypeModel>();
    categories.Add(new BIFireTypeModel() { ID = 1, Name = "IA" });
    categories.Add(new BIFireTypeModel() { ID = 2, Name = "Extended Attack" });
    categories.Add(new BIFireTypeModel() { ID = 3, Name = "Large Fire Support" });
    return categories; 
}        

public class ViewModelData
{
    public String IncidentNumber { get; set; }       
    public Product product { get; set; } 
}
```

And finally my cshtml:

```
@{

    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {     

        <h4>Incident Number</h4><input id="txtIncidentNumber" name="IncidentNumber" type="text" />           
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.product.CategoryID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Categories, "ID", "Name"))      


        @* WILL CAUSE IncidentNumber in BasicIdentificationIndex(ViewModelData product) TO BE NULL
        <h4>Incident Number</h4><input id="afasf" name="product.CategoryID" type="text" />
            *@

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In my Post function, I can access product.CategoryID with Request[] like so:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BasicIdentificationIndex(ViewModelData product)
    {
        String tmp = Request["product.CategoryID"];
        ViewBag.Categories = GetItems();    

        return View(product);           
    }
```

And it returns the right value. But this value will not bind in my model, and if I try to use DropDownListFor at all with product, ALL VALUES in ViewModelData product will be null.

Comment: Change the id to id="IncidentNumber"! Default model binder looks for Ids as the same properties on the request to build the model back in the server.

Comment: I thought it looked for name? And the IncidentNumber is working fine when I am not using product.CategoryID

Comment: Is this view strongly typed as ViewModelData? Why not just use Html to generate the field?

Comment: As Fals said, why not use @Html.TextBoxFor for the inputs?

Comment: @JohnEdwards It should look for `Id` but displays `Name` for user friendly

Comment: It is strongly typed as @model  AFUEMVC.Controllers.ViewModelData. I am very new to MVC(second day learning it) and I am just trying to save the state of some text boxes and drop downs on a form, and have them persist when going to other pages and coming back. But as I said, the text boxes save fine, it is the object I am having issues with.Thanks.

Comment: if you enter a value of `2` in the textbox with id `asasf`, will that set the value of the dropdown list to `Extended Attack` after a post?

Comment: That line is commented out with @* *@. It is hard to tell in stackoverflows comment box.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED:

Here is the issue.

```
public ActionResult BasicIdentificationIndex(ViewModelData product)

public class ViewModelData
{       
   public Employee product { get; set; } 
}
```

The NAME of my object in my ViewModelData was the same as the PARAMETER in BasicIdentificationIndex(). This caused major issues. All I had to do was change the name.

**EDIT:**
Something else that is very IMPORTANT is that when I was using EditorForModel(), my dropdowns weren't binding, but when I would manually create them with @Html.EnumDropDownListFor the binding worked. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example approach that populates three DropDownListFor at the same View:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class GroupViewModel
{  
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Schedules { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Labs { get; set; }
    public int LabId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Terms { get; set; } 
    public int TermId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //Populate DropDownList binding values
    var model = new GroupViewModel
    {
        //Preselect the Lab with id 2
        //LabId = 2,

        Labs = repository.Labs.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }),
        Terms = repository.Terms.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }),
        Schedules = repository.Schedules.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
    return PartialView("_Create", model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LabId, new SelectList(Model.Labs, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ScheduleId, new SelectList(Model.Schedules, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TermId, new SelectList(Model.Terms, "Value", "Text"), 
    "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

Hope this helps...