# How to convert SelectListItem to SelectList and assign to mvc dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Below is the collection of select list items:
I want to convert this selection item to SelectList and assign it to mvc dropdownlist.

```
List<SelectListItem>     Genderitems     =    new List<SelectListItem>();
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Other Gender", Value = "Other Gender" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Unspecified or Unknown", Value = "Unspecified or Unknown" });
```

Comment: The `DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` method accept `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the 2nd paramater, which is what you have. You don't (and should not) convert it to a `SelectList` (which **is** `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` anyway).

Comment: You might have a look at my answer on [ASP.NET MVC DropDownListFor Model binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696706/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-model-binding/39552222#39552222).

Answer (score 8):

May be you are looking for this

```
List<SelectListItem>     Genderitems     =    new List<SelectListItem>();
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Other Gender", Value = "Other Gender" });
Genderitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Unspecified or Unknown", Value = "Unspecified or Unknown" });
SelectList sl = new SelectList(Genderitems, "Value", "Text");
ViewBag.GenderList = sl;
```

In your View
if you do not want to stricly bound the selection to model

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpGender", ViewBag.GenderList as SelectList, "Select Gender", new { id = "drpGender"})
```

In other case you can

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Gender, ViewBag.GenderList as SelectList, " ", new { id = "drpGender"})
```

Comment: I believe that question is about "How to convert List<SelectListItem> to SelectList" and not about "How can I create a drop down"

Comment: yes.. i was going to ask this from @user3720460 but I don't have comments enabled yet so thought of answering which i faced sometime earlier

Answer (score 0):

Both `SelectList` and `List<SelectListItem>` are implementing an interface `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. And an extension method for creating drop down looks like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList);

public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList);
```

As you can see both extension methods are accepting `IEnumerable<SelectList>` instead of `SelectList` so, as @StephenMuecke noted, you have no need to convert `List<SelectListItem>` to `SelectList`.